# Live reloading React Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I am working on a react application with a nodejs(express) backend.

My question is about the best way to create a new webpack bundle and reload the browser after making changes in the react front end. I am thinking about something similar to nodemon in nodejs.

I've tried to use webpack-dev-server to create a new bundle each time I change something in react but ran into errors.

Is it possible to either:

1. Set up webpack to produce a new bundle each time I change something in react, while still using the nodejs backend?
2. Set up webpack to produce a new bundle each time I change something in react + reload the browser + use nodemon?
3. If not, what is the way to go if I want to create a new webpack bundle each time my react app changes?

Comment: are you using create-react-app?

Comment: no, I am using react in the client of my nodejs application.

Comment: Then check out my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You should use hot module replacement: https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/

Comment: Thx for the answer. Got it working as I wanted with the --watch flag from webpack itself ;)

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved my problem myself.

1. My goal was to have my nodejs(express) server running with my react application on the client side.
2. Also webpack should create a new bundle when something changes, so that when I reload the browser the changes are present.

To make this happen you have to execute two commands:

1. To build the webpack bundles if something changes:

`webpack --mode development --watch`

2. And the nodejs server with nodemon to reload when there are changes:

`nodemon src/bin/www`

Answer (score 0):

React gives you an application builder which supports those requirements you wanted.

**Please have a look here. [Create a New React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)**

Add webpack later in the dependancy tree after creating the app.

Comment: The create-react-app has such a feature but does not have a server coupled to it and that was my question about. Nevertheless, thx for your answer.